# Pass auth token for <audio> tag

Tags: html, audio

I have a system with two servers. The first server handles all authentication, authorization, etc. The second server handles all audio. When playing audio, the auth is performed by the first server, which signs an access token. The second server verifies the token and then permits playback.

The problem I am facing is getting the token on to the second server.

Currently I make a distinct AJAX request to the second server to set the auth token as a cookie. Then the browser sends the cookie with the reqeust. Unfortunately, this isn't sufficiently scalable on mobile devices, as the auth token is too big for their cookie limits.

What I could really use is if the `<audio>` element could be convinced to make a POST with a given body to get the audio, rather than a GET. Then I can just pass the auth token as part of the body.

How can I get my access token on to the second server for playback reliably and when supporting mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deconstructing the token and fortunately, the necessary constituent pieces can fit in the URL. However generally given the terrible QoI of the `<audio>` tag for basically all browsers and the lack of any kind of useful control, I think it's time to throw out the `<audio>` tag.